# Why render stops in save step in Blender?

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

i recently meet a wired problem, i am batch rendering image in blender  , 98% of them work normally , that is render and save without any problem, but some image render will freeze in the save process

Look the screenshot , other image render ends within 2 mins, but some image render will freeze , i have to press `Ctrl+C` to terminate the freeze stage so the rendering can go on , i really dont know why

[image]

Here is the render part of my codes , and everything is based on standard , but sometimes image will freeze in render save step!!

```
img_path="D:\example"
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = img_path
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

(i really wonder it is the BUG of Blender , if no efficient solution, i have to use multiprocess and pyclick to overcome this problem....,and i usually left the machine to render all day long , if one step freeze , it can cause super huge huge wastage !!!time and money!for example , today i lose around 5 dollars from this problem.. )

Comment: Have you accidentally clicked into the command prompt? This would activate the QuickEdit-mode and pause the application (similar to [T74995](https://developer.blender.org/T74995)).

Answer (score 0):

with the inspiration from comment user , problem figure out

this is the explicit tutorial to shut down this noise function

[How to shut down window console quick edit mode?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf9f97a1-ebbb-4f35-bbb6-6af740a71c76/how-to-disable-command-window-quick-edit-mode-once-and-for-all?forum=vcgeneral)